# Post status as Business Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am the admin of a Facebook Business page.

I want to be able to post a status **as the business**, **to the business'** wall.

Currently when run the following code...

```
$me=$facebook->api('/me');
$ID=$facebook->api('/ID');
$newMessage=$_POST["newMessage"];
$facebook->api('/ID/feed','post', array('message' => $newMessage));
```

... I post **as myself**, on my **own wall**.

Q. How do I change it so that I post as my business, to my business' wall?

Comment: Use a page access token. And make sure that ID is the page id

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting the error: (#200) Permissions error. Any ideas? I am admin of the page...

Comment: Are you using a page access token then?